# why does iostream header file not get included?

Tags: c++, io

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hi"; // error: undeclared cout
}
```

From what I have read, sstream class is derived from iostream class but why does it not get included automatically?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the sstream header file to see what is and isn't included?

Comment: It is not derived from the standard output though. std::cout is also derived from iostream but it is more than just that.

Comment: But when I derive classes i don't have to include base class headers. I don't know why does it not get included.

Answer (score 11):

The `iostream`-based classes are not the same as the `iostream` header. Standard headers do not have to include each other, or may include each other in any order. If you wish to use the contents of `<iostream>`, you must `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by iostream-based classes.

Comment: @user756327: Classes based on `std::ostream` and such.

Answer (score 1):

`std::sstream` is derived from both `std::istream` and `std::ostream`. That means you don't need to include `<istream>` or `<ostream>`. However, `std::cout` is defined in neither of those two headers. That's why you need yet another header, `<iostream>`.